# SQL DB selection in jfreechart servlet

Tags: java, sql, servlets, jfreechart, vaadin

I have a simple servlet wich generates a piechart. It gets the data from a sql DB like this :

```
    dataset.executeQuery("Select * From my_table");
```

so the chart can only show the data of my_table. what i want to do is to let the user (or the one with the permission like admin) to select a table from some DB he wants to be shown on the grafic

thats what i've been thinking off

Send a request  to list all of the available tables in the DB and show them to the user ( checkbox or ratio buttons)
then with the selected table the chart is generated ( button click) or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you solution is OK. Just remember to check table name on server-side after you get it from user to prevent `SQL`-injection (since malicious user can construct `HTTP` request by hand and pass in values not on the list).

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, you might also look at using one of the JDBC enabled data sets in [`org.jfree.data.jdbc`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/package-summary.html).